# Locating file path of image in android devices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, vuforia

sorry im very new to unity and c#.

Im trying to read an image and apply it as a texture.

The code works when i try it with an image on my computer, however, when i try it with my android devices (phone and AR glasses), i've not been able to specify the file path correctly. How do i specify the file path properly of android devices or is there a way i can get these file path?

Thank you so much for any help in advance! :)

```
void Start()
    {
        thisTexture = new Texture2D(100, 100);


        //string path = "C:/Users/kenny/Desktop/5th March/im.png";   //this works

        string path = "file:///storage/emulated/0/im2.png";         // this doesnt work

        bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        thisTexture.LoadImage(bytes);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = thisTexture;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For mobile devices it is not as straightforward to get a file from a plain path.

One way of doing so is by using the [Resources folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity6.html). In your root folder (*Assets*), create a new folder named *Resources*. Put your image there.

Then you can do something like this:

```
// path without file extension!
var texture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("path/to/texture");
```

You can get more references for this functionality here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-load-a-image-from-the-resources-folder-to-a-texture2d.101542/

Alternatively, you could use the [StreamingAssets folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html), but that's another story.